# Does any stat increase my Block Chance?

Tags: diablo-iii

Most shields I've seen around my level only have around a 15% block chance, although I have seen ones as high as 30%

Is this based on any particular stat, or is this a shield-specific value? And is there any way to raise my block chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no stats that provide a bonus to blocking. This was done to prevent any class from feeling as though they were 'designed' to use a shield. The only way to improve your chance to block is to equip a higher quality shield, or to find items with an Affix that increases your chance to block.

Comment: Wrong, see my answer

Comment: @pinouchon `or to find items with an Affix that increases your chance to block.` seems to cover your answer. What's wrong?

Comment: I miss read this sentence: `There are no stats that provide a bonus to blocking`. There is no skill stat that increase your block chance, but items other than shield that does.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the list of items that provide block chance, but as far as I know, [the helm of command](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/the-helm-of-command) gives +8% chance to block.

So with what is currently available on the AH, you can buy a [stormshield](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stormshield) (up to 32% block), [a helm of command](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/the-helm-of-command) (+8%), and a [justice lantern](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/justice-lantern). So you can have 51% block chance total. There are other items such as a belt with 5% block chance, but I think a [string of ears](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/string-of-ears) is better.

Prices on european servers:

- 31-32% stormshield - 10-30M gold (a sacred shield is a better purchase IMO)
- justice lantern - 3M hold
- helm of command with all resist: 3M gold, much more if you also want a socket.

---

Edit: If you want to see all of the items with block % other than shield, just search on the AH: armor / any armor type / block %.

Comment: There are items, it appears to be a stat that is possible on certain legendaries and has a minor possibility to appear on some other items as well.

Comment: +1 for your edit about finding these items. Saved me some time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the tool-tip in game block chance is only increased by skills and items. So unlike Dodge which is increased by Dexterity you are limited to the block chance you find on shields (and possibly other items?) and if you have any skills/passives that actively increase you block chance.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a +block% skill that can appear on items, however, I have only really seen it on shields.

Currently, that looks like the only way to directly improve your chance to block. However, there are plenty of other ways to mitigate damage through Dexterity and Intelligence as primaries, and stats like +physical resistance.

Comment: I've also seen that affix appear on Templar relics.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, 4 different items others than shields that can have block amount. So, you can have a maximum of 60% block chance.

Given Stormshield 32%, Justice Lantern 11%, Helm of Command 8%, Captain Crimson's Codpiece 4%, Kotuur's Brace 5% = 60% ... just that Crimson and Kotuur are not good for end-game. So, 51% is a reachable target without neglecting other stats.

Comment: There is an affix that increases block chance.  That does not answer the question, however: Does any *stat* (Strength, Dexterity, etc) increase my block chance?