# What is the maximum Block chance for An Impenetrable Defense?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/70136/51171) implies that there is no character statistic or class that helps blocking.  Is there a passive?  [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/73561/51171) lists some of the items that have the +% Chance to Block affix.  What are the best-in-slot items with +% Chance to Block?

This is relevant because the achievement [An Impenetrable Defense](http://www.diablowiki.net/An_Impenetrable_Defense) requires a Barbarian to block five attacks in a row.  The higher your block chance, the easier it is to get the achievement (I recommend an Iskatu run on Normal for that achievement).  What is the maximum Block chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are all the items that grant the highest block % in each slot:

- Helm: Helm of command 8%
- Ring1: Justice Lantern 11%
- Ring2: Legacy Justice Lantern 11%
- Belt: Kotuur's Brace 5%
- Weapon: Doombringer 7%
- Pants: Captain Crimson's Bowspirit 4%
- Shield: Stormshield up to 34%

With these items, it becomes nearly trivial to get the achievement.  However, note that some of these items aren't max level items so they aren't optimal for actual use outside of getting the achievement.

Comment: You're short the Legacy version of the Justice Lantern.  With it, you can get up to [80%](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9165487040#5).

Comment: @brythan true i forgot the game treated it as a separate unique

Comment: I got the achievement with just a cheap Stormshield in act IV quest 1, Fall of the High Heavens (normal).

Comment: With a crusader you can use the passive Hold Your Ground for +15% and Punish for another +15%. It is possible to have 100% block without the Legacy Justice Lantern while punish buff is up.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey this answer probably needs an update for 2.0 anyway.

Comment: @z- It probably does need update. I know that 2.0 Justice Lantern is now 12%.

Comment: @z- Also, rather than asking another duplicate I should just point out that we need updated information regarding new gems. There is an old answer regarding "Cumulative Cost" of combining.